# Django filter with date range list in orm

Tags: python, django, orm

Is there any way for filter with date range array in django orm?

example :

```
date_ranges = [["2011-01-01", "2011-01-31"],["2011-02-01", "2011-02-31"]]
Sample.objects.filter(date__range__in=date_ranges)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OR` query after looping in `date_ranges` like below.

```
 from django.db.models import Q

 query = ""

 for val in date_ranges:
      if (query == ""):
          query = Q(date__range=val)
      else:
          query = query + "|" + Q(date__range=val)
```

Now the query is formed using this query to filter.

```
 User.objects.filter(query)
```